# Redirect Search to Form When No Product Results Are Found

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, search

Site has an internal product search. If a query has no results, I want to redirect to a contact form, and pass the query through into the form into the product name field. The problem I'm having is with the conditional statement. I've written some code to determine if the query is a search, and if it has results. When I write an If statement with && it always evaluates to false. If I nest them as below, it works, but this cant be ideal. I'm sure the answer is simple, but I am not very familiar with php syntax.
Thanks.

```
function no_products_found_redirect($query) {

    $search = $query->query['s'];

    if ( $query->is_search() ){
        if ( have_posts() ) {
            echo 'dont do anything';
        }
        else{
            wp_redirect ( home_url('/request-quote/?product_name=')) . $search;
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'no_products_found_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 2):

`pre_get_posts` is fired before the query is run and is used to customize the query before its is run.

See here for a list of hooks, they are listed in order of execution. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

I would suggest using a hook that fires after the query is run for example, `template_redirect` is fired immediately after the query is run.

```
function no_products_found_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->is_search && !have_posts() ){
        wp_redirect ( home_url('/request-quote/?product_name=' . get_search_query() ) );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'no_products_found_redirect' );
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get this working using `the_posts` instead of `pre_get_posts` as you suggested. In case anyone runs into this in the future here is the final code.

Comment: `add_filter('the_posts', 'no_products_found_redirect', 10, 2);
function no_products_found_redirect($posts, $query){
    if($query->is_search && empty($posts)){
  $name = $query->query['s'];
  wp_redirect( home_url( '/request-quote/?product_name='). $name);
  exit;
    }
    return $posts;
}`